# jump-to-mark (C-u C-SPC) in emacs python mode not working

Tags: python, emacs

I have a simple question. Normally (and currently in other modes), after setting a mark with C-SPC, C-u C-SPC will return the cursor to that mark. However, in (Python) mode, and only (Python) mode, does that behavior not work, wherein it says "C-u C-SPC" is undefined.

I tried to look up the function and rebind it myself (i.e. C-h k then the command) but that returned as soon as I typed C-u. Can someone tell me the actual command C-u C-SPC invokes, 
and/or why (Python) mode seems to debind it?

Comment: You should do `C-h k C-SPACE`. The help for key sequences like `C-u <somekeys>` are mentioned in help of `<somekeys>`

Answer (score 0):

The actual command is `set-mark-command` bound to `C-SPC`, so you should be able to use `C-h k` `C-SPC` to see how it's bound. (`C-u` just adds a prefix argument).

For my emacs (24.3.1) `C-u` `C-SPC` works exactly as you say it should. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 23.3.1. I doubt it has todo with the emacs versioning, though, as the behavior works fine in non-(Python) modes. I'm betting one of the packages I've loaded for python is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

Works nicely from emacs -Q (python.el) as with python-mode.el

Also can't imagine one of the Python-IDE's out there took this key.

Maybe start from emacs -Q and load your init-file step by step.